# Как сделать свой цвет рамки в компоненте q-input, когда компонент не в фокусе

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors, бэм, quasar-framework

Использую [Quasar-Framework](https://quasar.dev).
Интересует возможность изменения цвета рамки `q-input`, когда он не в фокусе. 
По умолчанию, цвет рамки `q-input` серый, и только при фокусе обретает цвет, который был задан.

ps: `q-input` используется в режиме `outlined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цвета всех компонетов Quasar можно менять задавая css классы цветов у компонентов.
Классы с префиксом `bg-` отвечают за цвет фона.
Классы с префиксом `text-` отвечают за цвет текстового объекта (foreground).
Например, если мы хотим у компонента сделать фон жёлтым а текс синим то делаем классы

```
class="bg-yellow text-blue"
```

Цвета берутся из [Material Design палитры в Quasar](https://quasar.dev/style/color-palette#Color-List).
Так же можно использовать predefined цвета из material design палитры
`primary`, `secondary`, `ascent`, `warning`, `negative`, `positive`.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: {
    text: "Всем привет!"
  }
});
```

```css
/* Цвет рамки по умолчанию */
.q-field__control::before {
  border-color: red !important;
  border-width: 2px !important;
}


/* Цвет рамки при наведении мыши */
.q-field__control:hover::before {
  border-color: green !important;
}


/* Цвет рамки при фокусе */
.q-field--focused .q-field__control {
  color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-input class="bg-yellow my-border" label="Поле" outlined v-model="text"></q-input>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.9.12/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.9.12/dist/quasar.min.css">
```

PS: Обновил ответ.
Многие цвета которые нельзя задать напрямую можно задать напрямую через стили Quasar селекторов изучая стили в DevTools F12 в браузере. 
Пример для стилей рамок в коде.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность. Возможно, я некорректно задал вопрос.
В режиме outlined, цвет фона инпут становится белым, и закрашиваются границы инпута (border). 
ВОт как раз за цвет границы и был задан вопрос.

Comment: Если это ответ на ваш вопрос, отметьте пожалуйста ответ ответом.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что вы хотите в итоге получить?

Comment: Как задать цвет границы?

Comment: Лучший развернутый ответ!